# SaxParser Not Working to Extract Larger Strings Android

Tags: android

I am using SaxParser for parsing a XML which contains some image url which are long enough.
Using sax parser i am storing them in my variable. the code i wrote is simple and very accurate to parse as it is parsing the same xml accurately but with smaller length strings.

Which Ensure My Code Correctness. Its like SAXParser is failing in extracting larger strings.

help me out plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you are doing wrong. though it would be more better to answer if you post the code of yours.

You must be storing the character string in the character reading delegate of parser in some String Variable. Which is the problem .

instead you should use a String Builder and append the characters in a new buffer to extract the string from xml in the character reading delegate .

like this

```
   StringBuilder obj = new StringBuilder(); // some where in the starting tag delegate

   public void characters (char buf [], int offset, int len) throws SAXException
   {
        obj.append(buf);  
   }
```

This problem occurs  as many threads can be running at a time which sometime preempt the parsing thread.

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Great Man, Yes it was the problem and it is working now . i was thinking of posting the code but you caught it already.. I am thankful to you as you saved my day. I should have asked it earlier..

Thank You @Javanator

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try libroxml for android. (http://code.google.com/p/libroxml/ )